# Typeorm just run update if entity has changed

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

i have a task which is getting data from an api and stores it into my DB.
I the entities are pretty big, but i can identify if them easily by an id.
The biggest performance killer for me is now, that it runs many updates even if the object didn't change.
I run the save operation with reload disabled.
I need something like:
AfterLoad: save entity state (maybe the stringified JSON)
BeforeUpdate: Compare the new hash against the old hash - if no changes, don't run the update.

Is there anything like that available?
Or is it possible to prevent the update in the "BeforeUpdate" method?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [TypeORM hooks](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md), but I'm not sure.

Comment: i know about the hooks, but my question is, if i could do something like @BeforeUpdate: dontDoUpdate()

Comment: Did you find the solution? Naiively I would suspect that throws inside a beforeupdate hook effectively bans all update operations from calling `save`